# Access a new window - cypress.io

Tags: javascript, ui-automation, cypress

The question is as simple as that. In Cypress, how can I access a new window that opens up when running the test.

Steps to recreate :

> 1. Run the test. After some action, new window pops up (the url is dynamic in nature).
> 2. Fill in the fields in the new window, and click a few buttons.
> 3. After required actions are completed in the new Window, close the new window and move back to the main window.
> 4. Continue execution with the main window.

Point of interest: the focus should be

```
main window -> new window -> main window
```

I have read few things that relate to use of `iframe` and `confirmation box`, but here its none of those. Relates to accessing a whole new window. Something like [`Window Handlers`](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/switch-commands/) in Selenium. Unfortunately could not find anything related to it.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Accessing new windows via Cypress is [intentionally not supported](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/trade-offs.html#Multiple-tabs).

However, there are many ways this functionality can be tested in Cypress now. You can split up your tests into separate pieces and still have confidence that your application is covered.

> 1. Write a test to check that when performing the action in your app, the `window.open` event is called by using [`cy.spy()`](https://on.cypress.io/spy) to listen for a `window.open` event.

```
cy.visit('http://localhost:3000', {
  onBeforeLoad(win) {
    cy.stub(win, 'open')
  }
})

// Do the action in your app like cy.get('.open-window-btn').click()

cy.window().its('open').should('be.called')
```

> 2. In a new test, use [`cy.visit()`](https://on.cypress.io/visit) to go to the url that would have opened in the new window, fill in the fields and click the buttons like you would in a Cypress test.

```
cy.visit('http://localhost:3000/new-window')

// Do the actions you want to test in the new window
```

Fully working test example can be found [here](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/tree/94ae974f41ef579cdd4cb184ed852b623ef252f9/examples/stubbing-spying__window).

Comment: Hmmm. Roundabout way, but works I guess. One question. How do I get the URL from the button click. Assuming that the url changes each time I click it.

Comment: Um, more like in cases that : I don't know the url of the new window, how can I get it dynamically? I am thinking may be get the `href` attribute if its available? So is there a `.getattribute` function for such scenario?

Comment: Yes, you can always just use JavaScript.

    cy.get('a').then(($a) => {
      var url = $a[0].getAttribute('href') 
    })

Comment: Ok, thank you Jennifer. I'll check it out when I get time, but it should work perfectly well.

Comment: Would it be possible to get the instance of the window that just has been created? Becaus, my app has been made I cannot reach the new window by its URL

Comment: Is there a way to add the spy to the window inside an iframe? The app I'm testing is an iframe and calls window.open to open a pop up.

Comment: Also use Cypress.spy() on the window Object,
Okay but how can we access the newly opened window, while the test is running on the default window?

Comment: @JenniferShehane : I am facing similar issue but not able to resolve it out
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58328099/not-able-to-switch-windows-using-stub-and-spy-using-cypress

Comment: Current link of the "be.calledWith" implementation can be found at:
https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/tree/master/examples/stubbing-spying__window

Comment: "The web has evolved.
Finally, testing has too." - says Cypress. Apparently this evolved testing does not include such basic functionality as window handlers.

Comment: fwiw I used an alias for the stub, and then later used a matcher to confirm partial match: `cy.get('@facebookPopup').should('have.been.calledWith', Cypress.sinon.match('https://www.facebook.com/v2.1/dialog/oauth'))`

Comment: Could also get the full url with `cy.get('@facebookPopup').then(stub => {console.log(stub.getCall(0).args[0])})`

Comment: Hey, @patcon I didn't find any documentation from cypress regarding how to retrieve, handle, and check stubs. 

1. How did you figure out about the **getCall** method?
2. What other methods are there to use on the stubs?

Comment: Once we have access to the open window, how do we perform operations on it and then switch back to the old window? I could verify till the fact that window opened. But I am not able to find buttons on this opened window.

works- cy.window().then((win) => { cy.spy(win, 'open').as('windowOpen'); }); cy.get('button').contains('Sign in to your account').click() cy.get('@windowOpen').should('have.been.calledWith', Cypress.sinon.match('about:blank'))

This doesnt work - cy.get('@windowOpen').get('#buttonid1').click()

Also not sure how you move back to old window?

Comment: I want to check window.open is not called how can I do that ?

Answer (score 26):

I am not cypress expert, just started using it few days ago, but I figured out this kind solution for stateful application with dynamic link:

```
// Get window object
cy.window().then((win) => {
  // Replace window.open(url, target)-function with our own arrow function
  cy.stub(win, 'open', url => 
  {
    // change window location to be same as the popup url
    win.location.href = Cypress.config().baseUrl + url;
  }).as("popup") // alias it with popup, so we can wait refer it with @popup
})

// Click button which triggers javascript's window.open() call
cy.get("#buttonWhichOpensPopupWithDynamicUrl").click()

// Make sure that it triggered window.open function call
cy.get("@popup").should("be.called")

// Now we can continue integration testing for the new "popup tab" inside the same tab
```

Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Wow, work like charm! This should be documented in the official documentation.

Comment: Once we have access to the open window, how do we perform operations on it and then switch back to the old window? I could verify till the fact that window opened. But I am not able to find buttons on this opened window. works- cy.window().then((win) => { cy.spy(win, 'open').as('windowOpen'); }); cy.get('button').contains('Sign in to your account').click() cy.get('@windowOpen').should('have.been.calledWith', Cypress.sinon.match('about:blank')) This doesnt work - cy.get('@windowOpen').get('#buttonid1').click() Also not sure how you move back to old window?

Comment: This is great. It works as intended.

Answer (score 11):

```
// We can remove the offending attribute - target='_blank'
      // that would normally open content in a new tab.
      cy.get('#users').invoke('removeAttr', 'target').click()

      // after clicking the <a> we are now navigated to the
      // new page and we can assert that the url is correct
      cy.url().should('include', 'users.html')
```

[Cypress - tab handling anchor links](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/blob/master/examples/testing-dom__tab-handling-links/cypress/integration/tab_handling_anchor_links_spec.js)

Comment: A nice and simple hack. Many thanks.

Answer (score 11):

I was able to achieve the same requirement via the following:

```js
let newUrl = '';
cy.window().then((win) => {
  cy.stub(win, 'open').as('windowOpen').callsFake(url => {
    newUrl = url;
  });
})

cy.get('.open-window-btn').click()
cy.get('@windowOpen').should('be.called');
cy.visit(newUrl)
```

Comment: cy.window().its('open').should('be.not.be. called') can I do this

Answer (score 6):

Here's a solution i'm using on my project based on ["Cypress using child window"](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/cypress-using-child-window/)

[Cypress Window Helpers (aka. Cypress Tab Helpers)](https://github.com/jakedowns/CypressHelpers)
They're really popup-windows or child-windows, but i call them tabs for api brevity

```
cy.openTab(url, opts)
cy.tabVisit(url, window_name)
cy.switchToTab(tab_name)
cy.closeTab(index_or_name) - pass nothing to close active tab
cy.closeAllTabs() - except main root window
```

Answer (score 6):

I was recently faced with this issue as well - url for the new tab is dynamic, so I don't know what it is. After much searching, some trial and error, and input from co-workers, resolved by doing the following:

```
// AFTER cy.visit()
cy.window().then((win) => {
  cy.spy(win, 'open').as('windowOpen'); // 'spy' vs 'stub' lets the new tab still open if you are visually watching it
});
// perform action here [for me it was a button being clicked that eventually ended in a window.open]
// verify the window opened
// verify the first parameter is a string (this is the dynamic url) and the second is _blank (opens a new window)
cy.get('@windowOpen').should('be.calledWith', Cypress.sinon.match.string, '_blank');
```

Comment: Once we have access to the open window, how do we perform operations on it and then switch back to the old window? I could verify till the fact that window opened. But I am not able to find buttons on this opened window.

works- cy.window().then((win) => { cy.spy(win, 'open').as('windowOpen'); }); cy.get('button').contains('Sign in to your account').click() cy.get('@windowOpen').should('have.been.calledWith', Cypress.sinon.match('about:blank'))

This doesnt work - cy.get('@windowOpen').get('#buttonid1').click()

Also not sure how you move back to old window?

Comment: @namrata Cypress does not support multiple tabs. That is why my code is only verifying that window.open was called. In their [examples](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/blob/master/examples/testing-dom__tab-handling-links/cypress/integration/tab_handling_anchor_links_spec.js) they provide multiple ways to handle the new tab situation.

Comment: @namrata you have to turn off the chromewebsecurity in cypress.json. By default it’s value is true you can check in settings on cypress dashboard. For example please watch this video https://youtu.be/C2DjGl5a_-Y  starting 27th minute

Comment: cy.window().its('open').should('be.not.be. called') can I do this – 
Ankita

Comment: @Ankita If you want to verify it did not open, you want should('not.be.called') -- remove the extra 'be' at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

this is how you can handle tabs in same window..

use this code snippet

```
cy.xpath("//a[@href='http://www.selenium.dev']").invoke('removeAttr','target').click();
```

Answer (score 0):

what helped me:

```
    get myButton() { return cy.get('a') }

    cy.window().then((win) => {
        cy.stub(win, 'open').as('redirect').callsFake(url => {
            cy.visit(url);
        });
        myButton.invoke('removeAttr', 'target')
    });
    myButton.click();
```