# opening different domain as a popup for authenticatio on cypress.io

Tags: cypress

I would like to open a different domain url as a popup window for authentication and authorization.  Cypress.io does not allow a second unique domain.
I have found a related question answered here, about opening a new window with the same domain URL.

[Access a new window - cypress.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47749956/access-a-new-window-cypress-io)

I would like to know if it is possible to do this.

Example - Let's say my domain is abc.com,  Start functional test on abc.com   then open  xyz.com as a new window and confirm the user-entered parameter and close the xyz.com.

Comment: Could you clarify? Have you tried this yet?  If it hasn't worked, what was the problem?

Comment: I have added code here https://github.com/pravanjanDev/cypressDemo/blob/master/cypress/integration/open_windo_spec.js  . This example does work for same domain but it does not work if i open popup with a different domain. Its says failed  because your are attempting to visit second unique domain.

Comment: Did you came up with a final solution?

Comment: @muuvmuuv I have not found a quick solution so we decided to move to a different framework.

Comment: Found a way actually, just navigated in the main Cypress window, logged in, set cookie on server side, navigate back to our app. Its not the same flow as on the actual app, but enough to test.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your cypress.json file:

`"chromeWebSecurity": false`

This will allow you to visit and test other domains.  I have successfully used this on cypress.io on Windows 10 when testing (at least under Chrome); however, I don't know if you can rely on this in the future, so keep this in mind!

Comment: R. Brazell . I have already added the "chromeWebSecurity": false. But it does not work . The demo project is here in github .  https://github.com/pravanjanDev/cypressDemo/blob/master/cypress.json