# Cypress, get instance of new window

Tags: javascript, url, cypress

I found this: [Access a new window - cypress.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47749956/access-a-new-window-cypress-io)

I think it is a begining of something that might solve my problem. Though, a it doesn't solve my problem entirely.

Summary:

I have to run cypress test on a webapp. This webapp behaves this way:

http://urlofwebsite:1234/blabla/token -> open a new window

New window is at http://urlofwebsite:1234/blabla/page

The thing is, if I do something like `cy.visit("http://urlofwebsite:1234/blabla/page")` doesn't work. It opens new window the same way it did in the previous case.

That's why, I want to get the instance of this new window to run my test.

I don't know if I've been clear enough. Don't hesitate to question me (except Why is it made that way, because I don't know, I didn't do it).

Thank you all!

Comment: What happens if you open http://urlofwebsite:1234/blabla/page in regular browser window? Does it redirect you to /token page too?

Comment: No; it opens a browser

Comment: @YoannPicquenot got any Answer?

Comment: No. I wasn't able to find out a way of doing it.

Answer (score -1):

I found a way of doing this using Dr Gleb Bahmutov's ["Cypress using child window" blog post](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/cypress-using-child-window/).

I've extended his original helper command with some additional utilities: https://github.com/jakedowns/CypressHelpers

These helpers allow you to:
open a new window,
switch between them & test between them,
close your popup windows