# Test razorpay payment flow using cypress

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cypress, razorpay

I am trying to use [cypress](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress) for testing my Razorpay payment flow in my ROR project.I am able to get fields in iframe,select a bank and click on "Pay rs 399 now".On clicking the "Pay now button" a new window opens up which has two options to make the payment success OR fail it.Everything till now is already tested in cypress...My question is how do I access the new window opened using cypress and click "success"

### I HAVE TRIED:

As I was not able to access the new window.I tried adding a random *razorpay_payment_id* and amount and passing it directly using "POST" request to my "update" action in the Subscription Controller.But alas!!! this action  chks if *razorpay_payment_id* is present and if present fetches it like

```
payment = Razorpay::Payment.fetch(params[:razorpay_payment_id]).
capture({ amount: params[:amount] })
```

which errs to *"The id provided does not exist"*

#### Also tried:

refered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47749956/access-a-new-window-cypress-io) to access the new window...But got an err *"Expected "open" to be called at least once.But was never called"*

#### Please help!!

#### here are the images for ref

[(1)this image shows the razorpay modal before i finally click on pay button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gV3pU.jpg)
[(2)here is the new window which opens when I click PAY.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJKLI.jpg)