# How to verify element displays in new window after clicking a link on the main window

Tags: cypress, new-window

I am using Cypress to click a link on the Homepage which opens the respective page in the new window. I am not able to identify any element on this page. I am doing this to verify that the click opens the correct page.

I saw the link: [Access a new window - cypress.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47749956/access-a-new-window-cypress-io) which didn't help much to answer the problem.

Please suggest if there is some way to test this.

I have tried few things like:

```
cy.window().contains('.div.trItem')
cy.window().its('.trValue).should('eq','SomeHeading')
cy.url().should('include', '/theLink1.html/')
```

Expected: 
- Clicking link open the correct page in new window
- Identify URL in new window includes some text
- Certain text displays on the new window

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can't access to another tab or window with Cypress. Consider to separate your test cases. For example, in one test you could check that `a` element contains `href` attribute with expected url and `target` attribute with `_blank`.
Like this:

```js
it('contains valid a element', () => {
  cy.visit('https://example.cypress.io/')
  cy.contains('Cypress.io').should('have.attr', 'href', 'https://www.cypress.io').should('have.attr', 'target', '_blank')
})
```

And in second test check that your other page contains expected text.

Comment: I validated by separating the test cases. Thanks.