# Cypress execute non stop first attempt when retry functionality is enable

Tags: cypress

Our application uses as login method Microsoft Azure OAuth2. As result when the user tries to open the application is redirected Microsoft Azure login page. This redirection caused to me an issue when a test failed and Cypress tries to re-executed. So, when the test failed then Cypress window is reload and lost the information that test executed already once. As result re-execute non stop the first attempt. Please for your help on that.

Answer (score 1):

Cypress is focused in the testing of a single web page on purpose. But in your case it makes sense to trick cypress.
This must solve your issue: [Access a new window - cypress.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47749956/access-a-new-window-cypress-io)

Comment: @gugoplex thank for your answer. Login page is open in the same window. But my issue is not about redirection. My issue is based on retry functionality. When this functionality is enabled and the test failed then the test never moved to second attempt but retries forever the first attempt. This issues is happening because Cypress window is refreshing automated after the first attempt