# Cypress how to handle new tab without "target" and "href" attribute?

Tags: cypress, new-window, browser-tab

I am using [this](https://demoqa.com/browser-windows) example but I am not able to automate the "New Tab" button.

Here is a screenshot of the HTML document:
[image: Screenshot of the HTML]

I am trying to solve this by using the first answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47749956/access-a-new-window-cypress-io) topic.

```
/// <reference types="cypress" />
describe('Example shows how to work with browser windows.', () => {
  it('Example shows how to work within button that opens new tab without "target: _blank" and "href" attributes.', () => {
        cy.visit('https://demoqa.com/browser-windows')
        cy.window().then(win => {
            cy.stub(win, 'open').as('open')
          })

          cy.xpath('//*[@id="tabButton"]').click()
          cy.get('@open').should('have.been.calledOnceWithExactly', '/sample')
    })
})
```

I am not sure what I miss.

Comment: At July 2023 this works ok. `cy.xpath()` has been removed from Cypress so you must use `cy.get()` instead, but the test passes.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is not following the link's code you have provided. I have refactored your code, tested & it's working:

```js
/// <reference types="cypress" />
describe('Example shows how to work with browser windows.', () => {
  it('Example shows how to work witn button that opens new tab without "target: _blank" and "href" attributes.', () => {
      cy.visit('https://demoqa.com/browser-windows', {
        onBeforeLoad(win) {
          cy.stub(win, 'open')
        }
      });
    
      cy.get('#tabButton').click();
      cy.window().its('open').should('be.called');

      cy.get('#windowButton').click();
      cy.window().its('open').should('be.called');

      cy.get('#msgWindowButtonWrapper').click();
      cy.window().its('open').should('be.called');
  });
});
```

**Results:**

[image]

Comment: The code is working. Thanks. But I still can't get it. The page from the new tab doesn't open.

Comment: No, it won't open. Accessing new windows via Cypress is intentionally not supported. You can read more about it here: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/trade-offs#Multiple-tabs

Comment: Yes, I know that. But I was thinking that (somehow) we can open the new link in the same browser tab.

Comment: Well, you could visit the page after last assertion by adding `cy.visit()` method like so: `cy.visit('https://demoqa.com/sample');` aside from that, it's not supported.

Comment: Aha... so I need to know the URL before pressing the button. I can't inspect it or copy it. Ok... thanks for helping :).

Comment: Yeah, you can grab the `URL` using jQuery method to get the `attr` of the click element.

Comment: Ok, but in that case, we don't have "href" attribute. The hyperlink is not visible anywhere in the HTML document at all. In Selenium the solution is easy, we can switch to different tabs. It looks that in Cypress there isn't any working solution for this case. We are not able to grab the hyperlink from the newly opened tab. I guess there isn't a way to solve that by automation solution with Cypress.

Comment: Yeah, if you don't have `URL` it won't work visiting the new tab unless is hardcoded. As mentioned in the docs, it's not supported in Cypress.

Comment: Oh well... I tried to add attribute "target=_self" but with no sucksess - the attribute was added, but the link was opened again at the new tab. Ok the topic can be closed now.

Comment: @ManuelAbascal and  IvanMarkov  :  I too same issue where the does not have href and target attribute to switch to new tab and continue the execution on new tab. Any solution or work around found you guys.

Answer (score 0):

For all who search a way to handle new tab or new window with cypress you need this post [Testing PayPal checkout flow with Cypress](https://whattodevnow.medium.com/testing-paypal-checkout-flow-with-cypress-6c0ebd1321ff)

The most important part of code from that post is:

```
// Used to keep the reference to the popup window
  const state = {}

  /**
   * Intercepts calls to window.open() to keep a reference to the new window
   */
  Cypress.Commands.add('capturePopup', () => {
    cy.window().then((win) => {
      const open = win.open
      cy
        .stub(win, 'open')
        .callsFake((...params) => {
          // Capture the reference to the popup
          state.popup = open(...params)
          return state.popup
        })
    })
  })

  /**
   * Returns a wrapped body of a captured popup
   */
  Cypress.Commands.add('popup', () => {
    const popup = Cypress.$(state.popup.document)
    return cy.wrap(popup.contents().find('body'))
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
describe('Example shows how to work with browser windows.', () => {
    it('Example shows how to work witn button that opens new tab without "target: _blank" and "href" attributes.', () => {
        cy.visit('https://demoqa.com/browser-windows', {
          onBeforeLoad(win) {
            cy.stub(win, 'open')
          }
        });
      
        cy.get('#tabButton').click();
        cy.window().then(() => {
        cy.visit('https://demoqa.com/sample', { failOnStatusCode: false })
        })
        cy.get('#sampleHeading').should('have.text','This is a sample page')
        cy.go(-1)
        cy.get('#windowButton').click();
        cy.window().then(() => {
        cy.visit('https://demoqa.com/sample', { failOnStatusCode: false })
        })
        cy.go(-1)
  
        cy.get('#msgWindowButtonWrapper').click();
        cy.window().then(() => {
        cy.visit('https://demoqa.com/sample', { failOnStatusCode: false })
        })
    });
  });
```

If the element doesn't have an `<a>` tag, `target` and `href` attributes it will work this way.

Comment: Hi! The markdown layout looks a bit broken in the answer which makes it less readable. Please paste all code in the markdown code section to keep answer readable and clear.

Comment: Hi,
Now is it readable?

Answer (score 0):

```
cy.window().then((win) => {
  cy.stub(win, 'open').as("NewTabs")
})

cy.contains('button', 'buttonName').click()

cy.get("@NewTabs").should("be.called")
})
```