# Cypress - How to get url from result

Tags: javascript, automation, cypress

I'm a cypress beginner. I have a website and when I click on '**Login**' button ---> it opens a Microsoft login window. I want to access to MS login window to input my account BUT I don't know how to do it. Can anyone help me? I also try to perform like code

```js
describe('Login to PortalCX', () => {
  //let newUrl = '';
  it('login', () => {
    let newUrl = ''
    cy.visit('https://develop-portal.teamscx.com/', {
      onBeforeLoad(win){
        cy.stub(win, 'open').as('windowOpen').returnsThis()
      }
    })

    cy.get('[type="Submit"]').click()
  })

})
```

And it isn't work. But I see command log, I have a URL and I want to take this url to visit but I don't know how to do it. do we have the way to get this url? [image]

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to get the url from command log. you can use the concept of `cy.windows` for your problem. I would have tried this for this problem.

**Option 1:**

```
cy.window().then(win => {
      cy.wrap(win)
        .find('.email') // this is for Microsoft login email field (value can be change in your case)
        .type('your-email');

      cy.wrap(win)
        .find('.password') // this is for Microsoft login email field (value can be change in your case)
        .type('your-password');

      // Submit the login form
      cy.wrap(win)
        .find('.login-button')
        .click();
    });
  });
```

**Option 2:**

```
cy.window().then((win) => {
  // Replace window.open(url, target)-function with our own arrow function
  cy.stub(win, 'open', url => 
  {
    // change window location to be same as the popup url
    win.location.href = Cypress.config().baseUrl + url;
  }).as("popup") // alias it with popup, so we can wait refer it with @popup
})

// Click button which triggers javascript's window.open() call
cy.get("#buttonWhichOpensPopupWithDynamicUrl").click()

// Make sure that it triggered window.open function call
cy.get("@popup").should("be.called")

// Now we can continue integration testing for the new "popup tab" inside the same tab
```

**Note:** Use these as reference. [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47749956/access-a-new-window-cypress-io) [link2](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/window).

Above mentioned things may not fully solve your problems but they definitely can give you a concept/path to achieve what you want.

Comment: But with option 1 I can't action on ms pop-up. And with option 2: cy.stub() doesn't understand. Do you have any suggestions for me?

Comment: The code is just to guide you, that you can solve your problem  like this

Comment: oh Thanks, but my problem hasn't been resolved yet ^^